# Problem with background color on li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am setting background color of an `li` element by the code below :

```
$('#li123').animate({ backgroundColor:  color}, 'slow');
```

It works fine but the color spans whole length of `li`. What do I do if I want it to span the text contained in the `li` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the text inside the `li` in a `span` and do the `animate` on the span instead. If you need top and bottom margin of the animated area you could use `display: inline-block` on the `span`.

Comment: I thought so too, but it doesn't.

Comment: add css attribute `font-weight: bold;`

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

For your `<li>` add a `<span>`, enter your text in the span block and do a JQuery `animate` on that `span`. Your question isn't too clear though.

Comment: But I want to color the background.